# Convergent series? Gamma/power function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, divergent-series

Is it true to use as a general rule of thumb that the Gamma function always "kills" power function in a series? I mean:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{C^n}{\Gamma(n)^p}<\infty$$
no matter the constant $C>0$ and power $p>0$ in the gamma function as long as they are fixed and independent of $n$. Am I correct?

Now I wonder what happens with
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C^n \frac{\Gamma( a_n )^p}{\Gamma(b_n)^q}\, ?$$

How can we decide when the series is convergent? For instance if $a_n=b_n$ and $q>p>0$ I guess the series converges right? Is there a general rule/criterion one can use here? Actually, I have $a_n= an$ and $b_n=bn+c$ with $a,b,c>0$. I mean
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C^n \frac{\Gamma( an )^p}{\Gamma(bn+c)^q}\, ?$$
What would be the conditions on $p,q,a,b,c$ so that the sum converges?

Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: What are your restrictions on $C$ and $p$?

Comment: just (strictly) positive. $C,p,q>0$.

Comment: In the first part you should start with $n=1$ because $\Gamma(0)$ is undefined and assume $p>0$,

Answer (score 1):

First, simplify slightly (assuming a constant $p>0$ and $C>0$):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{C^{n}}{\Gamma(n)} = C\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{C^{n}}{n!}.$$

Here we used the fact that $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ and did a change of index.

Then, apply the ratio test.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\frac{C^{n+1}}{(n+1)!^{p}}}{\frac{C^{n}}{n!^p}}\right| &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{C^{n+1} n!^{p}}{C^{n}(n+1)!^{p}}\right| \\
&= |C| \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\right|^{p} \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
So the series converges.

Comment: (This is the proof of why you are correct... for the first question.)

Comment: Yes. Or using Stirling's formula. But what about the very last series with, $a,b,c,p,q>0$? When can I be sure that the series converges? I tried applying the ratio test and impose that the limit is less than 1 but didn't succeed.

Comment: You could get a "weak" result using the ratio test and Stirling's approximation.  In the sense that you'd have a slightly messy, limit and if the value of the limit was smaller than $\frac{1}{C}$ then the series would converge.